# I'm getting a long list of packages when creating a new python environment, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-20.04

I want to create an empty python virtualenv. Previously when I was on Windows, `python3 -m venv my_venv` created a virtual environment consisting of 3 packages only (pip, wheels and setuptools I believe), but now after moving to Ubuntu 20.04 my default packages when creating a virtualenv have changed:

```
angles==1.9.13
bondpy==1.8.6
camera-calibration==1.15.3
camera-calibration-parsers==1.12.0
catkin==0.8.10
controller-manager==0.19.5
controller-manager-msgs==0.19.5
cv-bridge==1.15.0
diagnostic-analysis==1.10.4
diagnostic-common-diagnostics==1.10.4
diagnostic-updater==1.10.4
dynamic-reconfigure==1.7.1
gazebo-plugins==2.9.2
gazebo-ros==2.9.2
gencpp==0.6.5
geneus==3.0.0
genlisp==0.4.18
genmsg==0.5.16
gennodejs==2.0.2
genpy==0.6.15
image-geometry==1.15.0
interactive-markers==1.12.0
joint-state-publisher==1.15.0
joint-state-publisher-gui==1.15.0
laser-geometry==1.6.7
message-filters==1.15.11
python-qt-binding==0.4.4
qt-dotgraph==0.4.2
qt-gui==0.4.2
qt-gui-cpp==0.4.2
qt-gui-py-common==0.4.2
resource-retriever==1.12.6
rosbag==1.15.11
rosboost-cfg==1.15.8
rosclean==1.15.8
roscreate==1.15.8
rosgraph==1.15.11
roslaunch==1.15.11
roslib==1.15.8
roslint==0.12.0
roslz4==1.15.11
rosmake==1.15.8
rosmaster==1.15.11
rosmsg==1.15.11
rosnode==1.15.11
rosparam==1.15.11
rospy==1.15.11
rosservice==1.15.11
rostest==1.15.11
rostopic==1.15.11
rosunit==1.15.8
roswtf==1.15.11
rqt-action==0.4.9
rqt-bag==0.5.1
rqt-bag-plugins==0.5.1
rqt-console==0.4.11
rqt-dep==0.4.12
rqt-graph==0.4.14
rqt-gui==0.5.2
rqt-gui-py==0.5.2
rqt-image-view==0.4.16
rqt-launch==0.4.9
rqt-logger-level==0.4.11
rqt-moveit==0.5.10
rqt-msg==0.4.10
rqt-nav-view==0.5.7
rqt-plot==0.4.13
rqt-pose-view==0.5.11
rqt-publisher==0.4.10
rqt-py-common==0.5.2
rqt-py-console==0.4.10
rqt-reconfigure==0.5.4
rqt-robot-dashboard==0.5.8
rqt-robot-monitor==0.5.13
rqt-robot-steering==0.5.12
rqt-runtime-monitor==0.5.9
rqt-rviz==0.7.0
rqt-service-caller==0.4.10
rqt-shell==0.4.11
rqt-srv==0.4.9
rqt-tf-tree==0.6.2
rqt-top==0.4.10
rqt-topic==0.4.12
rqt-web==0.4.10
rviz==1.14.8
sensor-msgs==1.13.1
smach==2.5.0
smach-ros==2.5.0
smclib==1.8.6
tf==1.13.2
tf-conversions==1.13.2
tf2-geometry-msgs==0.7.5
tf2-kdl==0.7.5
tf2-py==0.7.5
tf2-ros==0.7.5
topic-tools==1.15.11
xacro==1.14.8
```

I understand that most of these packages are not necessary when creating a python venv, how can I fix this?

Comment: Where do you see this list of packages?

Comment: I run `pip freeze`.

EDIT: I run this after activating the virtual environment, i.e. after running `source my_venv/bin/activate`

Comment: It is possible that your env was already activated previously? Try `deactivate`, remove the `my_venv` directory and create the env again

Comment: Definitely not activated previously... See these commands: 

```yemika@nitro:~/Mikael/Code/virtalenv_test$ ls
yemika@nitro:~/Mikael/Code/virtalenv_test$ which pip
/home/yemika/.local/bin/pip

yemika@nitro:~/Mikael/Code/virtalenv_test$ python3 -m venv my_env
yemika@nitro:~/Mikael/Code/virtalenv_test$ source my_env/bin/activate```

This again outputs a long list of packages as shown above in the question if I run `pip freeze`

Comment: What's in `/home/yemika/.local/bin/pip` exactly?

Comment: That's the global pip. I ran the `which pip` command to show that the virtual env was deactivated as @GonzaloOdiard asked.

Comment: Looks like you previously did a pip install without a virtualenv active

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: If you do a `pip install` but without a virtualenv active, the packages were installed in your user `./local/bin/pip`. In the practice, if you do not want these packages, you can remove that directory

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. But does it mean that these packages are also added to newly created virtual environments? There definitely wasn't such thing in Windows. I also had a lot of global packages installed, but they wouldn't leak into new environments.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem as you in the process of learning ROS2. And yes, there are so many modules from ROS in your list. Hence, I guess this is most likely because you have executed the command to source the setup script of ROS before your `pip freeze`.

You could try the following steps:

- find where the source command like `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.sh` is performed
- perhaps it locates in your global settings `/etc/environment`， `/etc/profile`, or your user files `~/.bashrc`, etc.
- remove the command and create a new terminal session, then pip will show the correct module list under your virtual environment

You may add the command back after this, but my recommendation is to source the ROS script manually only when you need it.